# Power Automate - Create Document Set with Metadata to SharePoint library

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, document-set, library, powerapps-forms

I have a SharePoint Online Library, with a customized PowerApps form.  I've been able to create a flow, and run it from my PowerApps form, to create a Document Set in my SharePoint Library.  My form also has several fields (choice, people, managed metadata) that I also want to populate in the new Doc Set that gets created.  What action(s) would I use in Power Automate to do this?  My "Create Document Set" button in my form has this OnSelect property - CreativeContractsCreateDocSet.Run(DataCardValue1.Text).  This creates the Document set successfully with the Name I entered (datacardvalue1).  How can I add more fields to also populate when the flow runs?

Thank you.

Comment: To populate additional fields when creating a Document Set in SharePoint using Power Automate, you can use the "Create file" action and set the file type to "Document Set". In the action, you can specify the folder path, file name, and metadata fields to populate. You can map the metadata fields to the corresponding values from your PowerApps form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the 'Send an HTTP request to SharePoint' action to create the document set from a specific content type.
2. Use another 'Send an HTTP request to SharePoint' action to set the specific metadata fields.
3. Add the 'Update file properties' action in SharePoint. Fill in all of your SharePoint fields per the inputs that you created in the trigger.

Let me know if this helps.

Ref: https://regarding365.com/creating-custom-document-sets-using-power-automate-875230441fd5